# Any way to get event, when some WPF data binding update occurs?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Any way to get event, when some WPF data binding update occurs?

UPD I'm developing a custom control extending one of standard controls. I need to get notification, when DataContext property of the ancestor control changes, or data binding causes update of any property of the ancestor control.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you require: [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) to be implemented on your View Model. This obviously depends on your implementation but this is assuming you've followed MVVM.

This then allows you to carry out some work based on the value of a bound property changing (and an event being raised).

Answer (score 3):

- As others already mentioned, if your object
  implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and
  the property supports it, register to [`PropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) and you will be informed about changes.
- If you are in a DependencyObject and add your own DependencyProperty, register a [DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencypropertychangedeventhandler.aspx) in the metadata to be informed when the property changes-
- If you have a DependencyObject and
  the property is a DependencyProperty, you can override
  [OnPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.onpropertychanged.aspx). It will be called
  every time, a DependencyProperty
  value has been changed. You can then filter out the property-changes you are interested in.
- If you are    outside of a
  DependencyObject and want to
  listen to a changed value of a DepenendencyProperty, you can use
  the [DependencyPropertyDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.dependencypropertydescriptor(v=VS.100).aspx) to register for [value changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dependencypropertydescriptor.addvaluechanged.aspx). However take care, using this may produce [memory-leaks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938416/en-us).

Comment: @user626528: If you want to be informed about changes of properties of your base class, then use the 3rd version I listed. Override OnPropertyChanged in your derived class and you will be informed about any change of any DependencyProperty inclusive the ancestors ones. If you mean with "ancestor" the parent of your class in the logical tree, then it will be a little more difficult. In this case you have to use the 4. version except for inheriting properties such as DataContext. Changes to inheriting DPs will also be reported through version 2 as long as they are not set explicitely.

Comment: @user626528: As an additon to my previous comment, please note that the OnPropertyChanged-method of the third version is not the same as the common OnPropertyChanged-method that is used for INotifyPropertyChanged. They have a different signatures, one is used for changes in DependencyProperties, the other is used for the broadcasting the PropertyChanged-event of INotifyPropertyChanged. Maybe this is a little confusing. Based on your comment, I assume really, that version 3 is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about getting a notification from a control perspective (i.e. when a dependency property has been bound to) you can provide a method that will be called passing the value:

```
public DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "ItemsSource",
                typeof(IList),
                typeof(CustomGridControl),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnItemsSourceChanged));

private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    e.NewValue;
}
```